# Crystal Report - How check if a string is in a entry on a array?

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, character

I would like to make a condition that look each element of a array and if the current element (string) possess a specific charactere, the condition return true.
More details: 
 The condition must be true if:
 - The first charactere is 1 and the third is in a IdList
 - The first charactere is 0 and the third is in a other IdList

I've try to do this, but it didn't work:

```
("1;" in {?dlcNatureProduit}[1 to 2] and {FournirRapportR39.NatureProduitType} in {?dlcNatureProduit}[3 to 4] ) 
OR
(CStr({FournirRapportR39.IdNatureProduit}) in {?dlcNatureProduit}[3 to 4])
```

The array look like this:
1;1
0;2
0;3
1;3
1;4
1;5
0;6
...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//create an array; split into tokens on ";"
Stringvar Array foo := Split(1;1 0;2 0;3 1;3 1;4 1;5 0;6, ";");

Numbervar i;

// examine all elements in the array
For i:=0 To Ubound(Foo) Do (

  // create second array base on first; split on " "
  Stringvar Bar := Split(Foo[i]," ");

  // first test
  If ToNumber(Bar[1])=1 And ToNumber([2])=[] Then
    //whatever

  ElseIf ToNumber(Bar[1])=1 And ToNumber([2])=[] Then
    // whatever

  ; // semi-colon might be required; doing this code from memory
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I done something similar that I put in a custom function and it's working as well.