# How to check the existence of a value in a String Array

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

I have a string array named "spools" that was built using a for loop. I am trying to print the array using a variable called display which prints as follows

1.00
2.00
3.00  etc

Now in my report I want to check a column value if it matches with one of the values, suppress the section. The condition used is "ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER}) in spools", which should occassionally print true or false.
However in my case it is always returing false. What could I be doing wrong

```
StringVar array spools := ['0'];
stringvar display;

if OnFirstRecord then
  spools[1] := ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER})
else (
  if not (ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER}) in spools) then (
    Local NumberVar i := ubound(spools) + 1;
    Redim Preserve spools[i];
    spools[i] := ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER});
display := display & spools[i]& chr(13)
  )
);

    display;
```

if my column value is returning 2.00, the condition should return true as the array at the time of printing record is [1.00 2.00]

Comment: See if the question asked here helps you at all.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603896/crystal-report-how-check-if-a-string-is-in-a-entry-on-a-array

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not setting the first value in your OnFirstRecord.

Change your code as follows:

```
StringVar array spools := ['0'];
stringvar display;

if OnFirstRecord then {
  spools[1] := ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER});
  display := spools[1]& chr(13)
} else (
  if not (ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER}) in spools) then (
    Local NumberVar i := ubound(spools) + 1;
    Redim Preserve spools[i];
    spools[i] := ToText({COESPOOL.LINENUMBER});
    display := display & spools[i]& chr(13)
  )
);

display;
```